# XNA keyboard input

Tags: c#, xna, switch-statement

I've got a small bug with registering the keyboard input.

```
       case GameState.InGame:
                {
                    **if (PlayerInput.IsKeyUp(Keys.P)&& oldInput.IsKeyDown(Keys.P))**
                         this.gameState = GameState.Paused;

                }
                   break;
            case GameState.Paused:
                {
                    **if (PlayerInput.IsKeyDown(Keys.P) && oldInput.IsKeyUp(Keys.P))**
                          this.gameState = GameState.InGame;
                }
                break;
```

---

What's happening is that it enters the pause game state just fine. But when trying to go from the pause state to InGame state is as soon as the 'P' key is up it goes back to paused state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you're testing for a key transition from UP to DOWN and in the second case from DOWN to UP. Use the same method for both cases.

Comment: lol thanks, that's a sure sign i need to get some sleep Haha! - Will accept as best answer when allowed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just toggle the game state when the button gets pressed.

```
if (PlayerInput.IsKeyDown(Keys.P) && oldInput.IsKeyUp(Keys.P))
{
  switch (this.gameState)
  {
    case GameState.Paused:
      this.gameState = GameState.InGame;
      break;
    case GameState.InGame:
      this.gameState = GameState.Paused;
      break;
  }
}
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
if (PlayerInput.IsKeyDown(Keys.P) && oldInput.IsKeyUp(Keys.P))
{
  this.gameState = this.gameState == GameState.Paused ? GameState.InGame : GameState.Paused;
}
```